# PHP Sessions Stop Working Automatically in Few Minutes for Paid Products Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress and Woocommerce, I am using PHP Sessions to Display Post ID in Email Notification, Sessions work fine with Free Product,
But When Product is paid/premium and got purchased with any Payment Method Option like PayPal, PayTM, PayUMoney, InstaMojo etc, Sessions work only for 10-15 mins and automatically got stop working, It's weird but I don't know why this happening.

One more thing I wanna mention when session stop working and I do any change in woocommerce code from Cpanel or Wordpress Admin Panel Like Enable/Disable Tax Option, Sessions Automatically start working again for next few minutes.

Page 1

```
    <?php session_start();
    $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
    $wp_session['regnumber'] = $post->ID;  ?>
```

Page2

```
        session_start();
        echo $wp_session['regnumber'];
```

Also Tried with $_SESSION

I want this session to work every time, or is there any alternate option available ?

Any Help will be appreciatable...

Comment: You're going to have to be a little bit more specific than "_automatically got stop working_"

Comment: Thanks for comment, I Explained the whole problem. @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: No you didn't, you just said it "doesn't work", what do you mean by "doesn't work"? What _does_ it do?

Comment: When Product is paid/premium and got purchased with any Payment Method Option like PayPal, PayTM, PayUMoney, InstaMojo etc, Sessions work only for 10-15 mins and automatically got stop working, It's weird but I don't know why this happening.
**doesn't work means Doesn't Print Anything**

Comment: That doesn't sound like an issue with sessions, it sounds like a 500 Internal Server Error, which means you need to enable error reporting in your server/website so you can see what the error is. We cannot help you with the little amount of information we have about your issue.

Comment: May be website issue, but not server, because I also tried this with Azure Servers and got same results.

Comment: Of course you got the same result, because it's an internal server error. Meaning it's the websites server side code (PHP) that is throwing an exception, which also stops execution of the code (hence; no output)

Comment: can you suggest me, how to enable error reporting for this issue, it should be from wordpress side or php,
Can you suggest me what should I do now ?
I am using Linux shared server with Cpanel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Please increase the session timeout . Check the site for reference : https://pc021.info/change-session-expire-time-in-wordpress/